# Maven can't resolve dependencies for project from archiva repo

Tags: dependencies, maven-3, archiva

we are using archiva and maven a long time. Everything works fine till now. A new developer started at our company and when he tries to set up his environment he gets that error:

```
13:41:50  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project our_project-util: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.corpintra.our_project:our_project-util:jar:2012.1: Failed to collect dependencies for [net.corpintra.our_project:our_project-mda:pom:2012.1 (runtime?), commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3 (compile), org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA (compile), commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 (compile), com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.38 (compile), org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.1.0 (compile), aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.3 (compile), jboss:jboss-j2ee:jar:4.2.2.GA (provided), commons-net:commons-net:jar:1.4.1 (compile), org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.3 (compile), org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1 (compile), org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-core:jar:1.2.6 (compile), org.codehaus.xfire:xfire-aegis:jar:1.2.6 (compile), org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:jar:5.5.0 (compile), org.apache.activemq:activemq-pool:jar:5.5.0 (compile), net.corpintra.client.util:rar:jar:1.1 (compile), org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.47 (compile), org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk15on:jar:1.47 (compile), com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7 (compile), commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1 (compile), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.andromda.profiles.uml2:andromda-profile:xml.zip:3.4-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.andromda:andromda:pom:3.4-20120529.073812-11 from/to archiva.default (http://svn.ssc-services.de/archiva/repository/internal/): Failed to transfer file: http://svn.ssc-services.de/archiva/repository/internal/org/andromda/andromda/3.4-SNAPSHOT/andromda-3.4-20120529.073812-11.pom. Return code is: 500, ReasonPhrase:Unable to fetch artifact resource.. -> [Help 1]
13:41:50  [ERROR] 
13:41:50  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
13:41:50  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
13:41:50  [ERROR] 
13:41:50  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
13:41:50  [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
13:41:50  [ERROR] 
13:41:50  [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
13:41:50  [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :our_project-util
```

We are using archiva as local repository. Archiva contains all external projects an our internal stuff. If the new developer gets a .m2 repo from me, all is fine. If he deletes my .m2 repo, he gets the same error. The same occurs if i delete my repository.

His settings.xml looks like this:

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>archiva.default</id>
            <url>http://svn.our_company.com/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
            [... some profile stuff ...]
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

Did anyone know this problem and can tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Based on the given error message

```
Return code is: 500, ReasonPhrase:Unable to fetch artifact resource.. -> [Help 1]
```

which means internal server error you have a problem with accessing the Archive...Have you tried to access the given artifacts via browser?

Comment: The artifact "andromda-3.4-20120529.073812-11" is not available at our repository, because this snapshot does not exist. The question is, why maven want this snapshot version instead of "andromda-3.4"? This artifact is available and used by all other developers.